# How can I solve an exponential inequality in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I would like to solve the equation:

```
A Exp[m t + s Sqrt[t] x - 1/2 s^2 t] >= K
```

with respect to `x` (which is in the exponent) using *Mathematica*. All parameters are positive. Of course, the answer is easy to get by hand. However, for some reason I could not figure out how to do it with *Mathematica*. What I tried gave me some error messages.

Also, I would like the solution to be expressed without all those conditionals. That is, I want the answer in which all the parameters satisfy whatever they need to satisfy so that the generic solution holds,

I would greatly appreciate help in figuring out how to do this.

Comment: "gave me some error messages when I tried" — Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: A kickstart `Reduce[a Exp[m t + s Sqrt[t] x - 1/2 s^2 t] >= k, x, Reals]`

Comment: Note how @belisarius replaced `K` `A` with `k` `a`, this is because things starting with an upper-case letter are reserved for built-in functionality and it's good practice to avoid that or it will bite you in the ass

Comment: Tried it before, but get totally wrong solution. Have you tried it? Works OK if I replace Sqrt[t] with some variable say p, but still get huge mess of an expression (lots of extra conditions.

Comment: Perhaps you can [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refine.html) it with some extra [assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html)

Comment: @ssch Not precisely true. Capital letters are used by a lot of third party packages, also, and there is nothing in the language that prevents this. It is a good recommendation, though, and if you decide not to follow it, you need to be careful. For the most part, I choose to ignore it, and capitalize my function names and lower case is used for my variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `k-> koa, a->1, Sqrt[t]->tt` (since they're all positive parameters) then

```
Reduce[{ Exp[m tt^2 + s tt x - 1/2 s^2 tt^2] >= koa, m > 0, tt > 0, s > 0, koa > 0}, x, Reals]

(* koa > 0 && m > 0 && s > 0 && tt > 0 && 
   x >= (-2 m tt^2 + s^2 tt^2 + 2 Log[koa])/(2 s tt) *)
```